# .net framework for working with units

Tags: c#, .net

Does somebody know a framework or library with which I can work in a compiler-checked manner with units? I would love to write

```
Speed mph = Length.mile / Time.hour;
Speed kmh = Length.km / Time.hour;
ValueWithUnit<Speed> _5mph = new ValueWithUnit<Speed>(5, mph);
ValueWithUnit<Speed> inKmh = _5mph.ConvertTo(kmh);
```

Having my unit conversions to be compiler checked would be another benefit and conversion factors could be derived from the way units are declared (km is 1000 times a meter and hour is 3600 times a second).

Comment: What about https://github.com/objorke/QuantityTypes ?

Comment: Asking for libraries is off topic on SO

Comment: Have you tried F#? That has units of measure built into the language.

Comment: Sorry for posting. Didn't know it was off-topic.